# Add spacing between two fixed elements

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements. Both elements have the same CSS code where they are on top of each other. However, what I'd like to do is for the bottom most element `.bar` to give spacing to `.bar2`. Imagine `.bar` being a bottom mobile navigation bar and `.bar2` being a settings menu. Both have `bottom: 0` CSS, however, I don't want them to sit on top of each other. `.bar` should have its own spacing so `.bar2` can be fully shown. How would I do that? Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snvdq031/1/)

I know I can do this by just adding `bottom` to `.bar2` but I don't want to move `.bar2` I want `.bar` to give invisible padding for `.bar2`

```css
.bar2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.3rem 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.3rem 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar2">
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple way by giving CSS property to the `.bar2` class, you have to set as following

```
.bar2 {
  bottom: /*.bar height in pixel*/
}
```

Suppose your `.bar` height is `50px` then bottom of `.bar2` is `50px`.

Comment: I know I can do it with bar2, but I'd like to give some sort of invisible padding with `.bar` so that it can push up `.bar2`

Answer (score 0):

You want somthing like this

```css
.bar2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height:40px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.3rem 2rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 5;
}


.bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.3rem 2rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar2">
  <div class="item">
   
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="item">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to move bar2 though

Comment: Check now i have increased height without moving it

Comment: I dont want to change anything with .bar2, I just want .bar to give the spacing that .bar2 needs

Answer (score 0):

add height to your both components bar1 and bar2 or any one components height is ok and then give margin as you want give that components